# Transaction commands executing but not reflecting in db c#

Tags: c#, rollback

The below code is to insert student details and run 3 stored procedures (all on cmd1).  I have used 
transaction and rollback for the same. All 4 executenonquery() are executed but nothing is reflected in the database.
Can anyone explain what is wrong or why it is not affecting the database?

```
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd1 = con.CreateCommand();
SqlTransaction transaction1;
transaction1 = con.BeginTransaction("Save Update Student");
cmd1.Connection = con;
cmd1.Transaction = transaction1;
try
{
    //sp to autogenerate student code in system..
    cmd1.CommandText = "sp_AutoGenerateStudentCode";
    cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cmd1.Parameters.Add("@std", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = cb_std.SelectedItem.ToString();
    cmd1.Parameters.Add("@div", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = cb_div.SelectedItem;
    cmd1.Parameters.Add("@Rollno", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txt_roll.Text;
    cmd1.Parameters.Add("@ReturnValue", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txt_name.Text;
    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();

    cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd1.CommandText = "insert into StudentMaster(GrNo,Name,DOB,Std,Div,RollNo,MobileNo,Address,TelNo,FathersName,FathersProfession,MothersName,MothersProfession,Age,Year,status,DOE,BookNo,FeesStatus,FthrsQlfction,FthrsOfcAdd,FthrsPhone,MthrsPhone,MthrsOfcAdd,MthrsQlfction,Bloodgrp,caste,Nationality,MotherTongue,PreviousSchool,Religion,height,weight,sex,SCode,EmailId)values ('" + txt_Grno.Text + "','" + txt_name.Text + "',@DOB,'" + cb_std.SelectedItem + "','" + cb_div.SelectedItem + "','" + txt_roll.Text + "','" + txt_mobile.Text + "','" + Rtxt_ResiAdd.Text + "','" + txt_Phone.Text + "','" + txt_fname.Text + "','" + txt_fOccu.Text + "','" + txt_mName.Text + "','" + txt_mOccu.Text + "','" + txt_Age.Text + "',getDate(),'" + cb_status.SelectedItem + "',@DOE,'" + txt_bookno.Text + "','" + cb_feestat.SelectedItem + "','" + txt_fQualificatn.Text + "','" + Rtxt_fOfcAdd.Text + "','" + txt_fPhone.Text + "','" + txt_mPhone.Text + "','" + Rtxt_mOfcAdd.Text + "','" + txt_mQualificatn.Text + "','" + cb_BldGrp.SelectedItem + "','" + txt_caste.Text + "','" + txt_Nationality.Text + "','" + txt_MthrTng.Text + "','" + txt_PrevSchool.Text + "','" + txt_Relgn.Text + "','" + masktb_hgt.Text + "','" + masktb_wgt.Text + "','" + cb_Gender.SelectedItem + "','scode','" + txt_email.Text + "')";

    cmd1.Parameters.Add("@DOE", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dateTimePicker1.Value;
    cmd1.Parameters.Add("@DOB", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dateTimePicker2.Value;
    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();

    cmd1.CommandText = "PrimaryFeesMainUpdate";
    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();

    cmd1.CommandText = "FEE";
    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();

    con.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("Record Added Successfully", "Success");
    button2_Click(null, null);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Commit Exception Type: {0}", ex.GetType());
    Console.WriteLine("  Message: {0}", ex.Message);

    // Attempt to roll back the transaction. 
    try
    {
        transaction1.Rollback();
    }
    catch (Exception ex2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Rollback Exception Type: {0}", ex2.GetType());
        Console.WriteLine("  Message: {0}", ex2.Message);
    }
}
con.Close();
```

Comment: Where's your `Commit`?

Comment: Use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) instead of string concatenation. Be aware of [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: @SonerGönül Is correct too. Why are you only doing DOE and DOB as parameterized and concatenating the rest?

Comment: thank you all for your reply and suggestions , @soner: i have been through sql injection and ill be writing the code in parameterized query as well..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must commit your transaction, as follows:

```
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd1 = con.CreateCommand();
SqlTransaction transaction1;
transaction1 = con.BeginTransaction("Save Update Student");
cmd1.Connection = con;
cmd1.Transaction = transaction1;
try
{
    //sp to autogenerate student code in system..
    cmd1.CommandText = "sp_AutoGenerateStudentCode";
    cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cmd1.Parameters.Add("@std", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = cb_std.SelectedItem.ToString();
    cmd1.Parameters.Add("@div", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = cb_div.SelectedItem;
    cmd1.Parameters.Add("@Rollno", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txt_roll.Text;
    cmd1.Parameters.Add("@ReturnValue", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txt_name.Text;
    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();

    cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd1.CommandText = "insert into StudentMaster(GrNo,Name,DOB,Std,Div,RollNo,MobileNo,Address,TelNo,FathersName,FathersProfession,MothersName,MothersProfession,Age,Year,status,DOE,BookNo,FeesStatus,FthrsQlfction,FthrsOfcAdd,FthrsPhone,MthrsPhone,MthrsOfcAdd,MthrsQlfction,Bloodgrp,caste,Nationality,MotherTongue,PreviousSchool,Religion,height,weight,sex,SCode,EmailId)values ('" + txt_Grno.Text + "','" + txt_name.Text + "',@DOB,'" + cb_std.SelectedItem + "','" + cb_div.SelectedItem + "','" + txt_roll.Text + "','" + txt_mobile.Text + "','" + Rtxt_ResiAdd.Text + "','" + txt_Phone.Text + "','" + txt_fname.Text + "','" + txt_fOccu.Text + "','" + txt_mName.Text + "','" + txt_mOccu.Text + "','" + txt_Age.Text + "',getDate(),'" + cb_status.SelectedItem + "',@DOE,'" + txt_bookno.Text + "','" + cb_feestat.SelectedItem + "','" + txt_fQualificatn.Text + "','" + Rtxt_fOfcAdd.Text + "','" + txt_fPhone.Text + "','" + txt_mPhone.Text + "','" + Rtxt_mOfcAdd.Text + "','" + txt_mQualificatn.Text + "','" + cb_BldGrp.SelectedItem + "','" + txt_caste.Text + "','" + txt_Nationality.Text + "','" + txt_MthrTng.Text + "','" + txt_PrevSchool.Text + "','" + txt_Relgn.Text + "','" + masktb_hgt.Text + "','" + masktb_wgt.Text + "','" + cb_Gender.SelectedItem + "','scode','" + txt_email.Text + "')";

    cmd1.Parameters.Add("@DOE", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dateTimePicker1.Value;
    cmd1.Parameters.Add("@DOB", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dateTimePicker2.Value;
    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();

    cmd1.CommandText = "PrimaryFeesMainUpdate";
    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();

    cmd1.CommandText = "FEE";
    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();

    // COMMIT THE TRANSACTION!        
    transaction1.Commit();

    con.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("Record Added Successfully", "Success");
    button2_Click(null, null);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Commit Exception Type: {0}", ex.GetType());
    Console.WriteLine("  Message: {0}", ex.Message);

    // Attempt to roll back the transaction. 
    try
    {
        transaction1.Rollback();
    }
    catch (Exception ex2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Rollback Exception Type: {0}", ex2.GetType());
        Console.WriteLine("  Message: {0}", ex2.Message);
    }
}
con.Close();
```

Answer (score 3):

Call `Commit` after you execute the last command:

```
cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
transaction1.Commit();
```